# Browsers not caching images from s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, caching, browser, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm hosting my personal portfolio on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, using s3 to store all the data, such as images, entries etc. This uses Django for the backend, and Reactjs for the frontend.

When loading the content, the browser makes a request which gets these datapoints

```
const getAllNodes = () => {
    fetch("./api/my-data?format=json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setMyData(data);
        });
};
```

The returned values are the file image urls, something along the lines of

```
https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-000000000000.s3.amazonaws.com/api/media/me/pic.png
```

with the following options

```
?X-Amz-Algorithm=XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX
&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
&X-Amz-Date=20230102T182512Z
&X-Amz-Expires=600
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

When using this method of image storage and retreival, the images don't seem to be cached on the browser, so they have to be fetched every time, and slow down the site's functioning on subsequent visits.

The following is a screenshot of the network tab when loading my site. Note how the images aren't cached

[image: images not being loaded from cache]

How should I handle this situation? I would like to store the images in the database (and therefore on s3) so I can update them as necessary, but also have the advantage of having them be cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is not good solution to cache objects but It still supports to browser cache files for a while.

You can add some custom metadata (header) for s3 objects to browser cache it.

[image: S3 object header]

Comment: what would be an alternative way to handle this?

Comment: AWS Cloudfront  is a global CDN solution

Comment: How would I set up my elastic beanstalk or s3 bucket to take advantage of that? And how would I get the files uploaded to RDS to work properly on it?

Comment: In a nutshell: Set up a Cloudfront distribution, add the S3 bucket as origin (with Origin Access Identity and a corresponding policy). In your application, reference static assets via their Cloudfront URL.

Comment: Amazing! Got it working. Unfortunately, I needed to enable fully public access to all objects in the bucket as I was getting 403 errors (Using Cloudfront disabled the generation of all those Amz headers). This isn't a big issue as this site is a public portfolio site, however, I was wondering how I'd get past this, if for example, this site required authentication, roles, and for not all images to be visible by all users?